WooCommerce - Order products by most popular but override for some products
I have my products ordered by most sold, with the built in function in Woocommerce. But I want to put a few products on the top even if they are not the most sold. Can this be done with some custom code?
For example, create a custom sort by most sold, but if these products ID(s) are present, put them on top?

I manage to solve this by using this code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {
  if (is_product_category( array( 'cat-123' ))) {
    return 'date';
  }
}

For a specific category I change the orderby to date and then set date accordingly as the order that I want. The rest of the products in all the other categories are sorted by most sold.
Not the way I asked the question, but its another way to achieve what I want.

To arrange your product as your wish you can use plugins like:

Rearrange Woocommerce Products

. And also you can use WooCommerce settings too. You can change menu order as you wish.
path:
Edit of any individual product → scroll down to the Product data widget → click on the Advanced tab, where you will find the Menu order for changing the order.

or you can

Adjust Sold Count

of your products..

Thanks for your comment. I have +70 categories and but only want to lift up a few products in one or two categories so a plugin feels overkill here. I have tried the menu order field under Advanced for each product but that does not work unless you have setup for custom order, not by most sold unfortunately.

i got your point, can't your increase your sold count in your products?

Thats a good point, have been thinking about it but I have to check so it does not mess up the statistics.

yeh, or will see another good solution.
